# Checking items in text Array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a scenario where i need to select rows by matching the items present in one of the columns of the table,

My table looks like below,

```
create table Arraycheck
(
    empnames text[],
    age int
)

insert into Arraycheck (empnames,age) values ('{vin,vinod,hyv,bang}'::text[],12);
insert into Arraycheck (empnames,age) values ('{bangalore,bengaluru,bang}'::text[],13);
```

**Case 1 :**
I want to select the rows whose empnames has 'vin' in it. I used the below query and it works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM Arraycheck WHERE 'vin' = ANY (empnames);
```

**Case 2:**

Now i want to select rows which has both 'vin' and 'bang'. I am unable to find query for this,

Can some one guide me here. I am using spring jdbctemplate. i need to use this query in spring jdbctemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the postgres `@>` operator:

```
select * from arraycheck where empnames @> '{vin,bang}';
```

It returns true if the array on the left contains all elements of the array on the right.

If you want matches that contain any (rather than all) of the items, use the `&&` operator (overlap):

```
select * from arraycheck where empnames && '{vin,bang}';
```